# Categorizing list of variables based on defined attributes

Tags: python

I'm running Python 3.7 in PyCharm, and would like to know how best to open and read a text file that contains a list of five multi-lingual students and their languages, and then, I would like to categorize each student based on whether they have a certain desired language. Some of the students speak one or more of the desired languages, but I only want to have their names listed once based on the following

1) students who speak Arabic;

2) students who don't speak Arabic but speak English;

3) students who don't speak Arabic or English but speak French.

students.txt (5 students [unsorted] in the class)

```
John Arabic,
Ron French,
John French,
Jane French,
Pat English,
John French,
Jane Arabic,
Pat Spanish,
Ron English,
Sarah French,
```

Results would look like:

```
John Arabic
Jane Arabic
Pat English
Ron English
Sarah French
```

I've been playing with this for hours and haven't had luck figuring it out. I've tried everything from looping things into a list and testing if things were in there, nesting if statements, and basic regular expressions, but I haven't had much luck. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Here is what I had come up with, but working.

```
def clean_up():
    final_list = []
    no_list = []
    with open('student.txt', "r") as infile:
        for lines in infile.read().strip().splitlines():
            line = lines.split()
            if lines in final_list:
                continue
            if findwholeword(line[0], 1, 'Arabic', lines) != (None or 
[]):
                no_list.append(line[0])
                final_list.append(lines)
            elif findwholeword(line[0], 1, 'English', lines) != (None 
or []):
                if line[0] in no_list:
                    continue
                elif line[0] not in no_list:
                    final_list.append(lines)
                    no_list.append(line[0])
                else:
                    print("Issue at 'NO' statement")
            elif findwholeword(line[0], 1, 'French', lines) != (None 
or []):
                if line[0] in no_list:
                    continue
                elif line[0] not in no_list:
                    final_list.append(lines)
                    no_list.append(line[0])
                else:
                   print("Issue at 'Error' statement.")
           else:
                print('Something went wrong!')


def findwholeword(w1, w2, w3, target):
    return re.compile(r'\b{0}(?:\W+\w+){{0,{1}}}\W+{2}\b'.format(w1, 
w2, w3), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search(target)

clean_up()
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] to show the specific problem with that you've done.

Comment: You know about dictonarys in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a defaultdict to create and language-to-name mapping, then use a set to skip over names you've already output:

```
from collections import defaultdict

languages = defaultdict(list)

with open('students.txt') as f_in:
    for student in f_in:
        name, lang = student.rstrip('\n,').split()
        languages[lang].append(name)

seen = set()
for lang in ['Arabic', 'English', 'French']:
    for name in languages[lang]:
        if name not in seen:
            print(name, lang)
            seen.add(name)
```

Output:

```
John Arabic
Jane Arabic
Pat English
Ron English
Sarah French
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you for taking the time to respond and help me solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import re
f=open('students.txt',"r")
arabic_list=[]
english_list=[]
french_list=[]
for i in f.readlines():
    i=re.sub('\n','',i)
    if 'Arabic' in i:
        arabic_list.append(i)
    elif 'English' in i:
        english_list.append(i)
    else:
        french_list.append(i)

lang_dict={'arabic':arabic_list,'english':english_list,'french':french_list}
for lang in lang_dict:
    for students in lang_dict[lang]:
        print(students)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm looking sort the five students based on the languages of Arabic, English, and French. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not optimal but could be something like this:

```
with open("students.txt","r") as rawdata:
    raw_list = rawdata.readlines()

new_dict = {}

for i in raw_list:
    name, language  = i.split(" ")
    if name in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict[name] += [language[:-2]]
    else:
        new_dict[name] = [language[:-2]]

language_order_list=["Arabic","English","French"]

for language in language_order_list:
    for name in new_dict.keys():
        if language in new_dict[name]:
            print(f"{name} {language}")
            new_dict[name] = []
```